ROS: Using rosdep to know the dependencies of package
This is all about a package and its dependencies.
For example, a project called cpp_pubsub with the usual file-structure after performing ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake cpp_pubsub.
The question is simple, given a ROS package, is it possible to list all the required dependencies using rosdep?
I have tried the following
rosdep keys -s --from-paths ros2_ws/ --ignore-src

Is this correct?
Any kind of assistance will be appreciated :)

I think you can use rospack in order to get the dependencies of a package. I suppose this is stil used in ROS 2, here is a link where you can find information about all the commands that it enables (link here)

I have tried this with no luck. Maybe I am using it wrong.
I have installed rospack via apt. I have a simple package under ros2 called cpp_pubsub. I used the command rospack deps cpp_pubsub but I am getting the error [rospack] Error: no such package cpp_pubsub.
I know my package is built and recognised by ros2 as I can see it in the list using ros2 pkg list command.
Any tips?

It's been a while since I worked with ROS 2. I had no success on seeing if this feature has been pushed to ROS 2 as well. Instead, I found a workaround using colcon, maybe this is fine for you? Althought, I must say that it isn't the best imo. Please take a look at this linkcolcon graph. In resume, you  have to use colcon graph inside your workspace, and it will mention all the packages inside your workspace, and relate them by their dependencies.
